# PHP modify dynamic variable names to static variable name

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic-variables

Please excuse me if I am asking a wrong question or impossible one, I am a newbie to PHP. I have following PHP code

```
    <?php
    if ($this->arrCustomFields) {
        foreach ($this->arrCustomFields as $field) {

            if($field['blnView']) {
                echo 'var '.preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($field['lbl']->Name)).' = "'.$field['lbl']->Text.'";';
            }

        }

    }
?>
```

This code produces following variable that I use in a javascript on the same page.

> ```
> var optic_drive = "No CD/DVD Media Installed";
> var power_supply = "No PSU";
> var ram = "2 GB";
> var web_cam = "No";
> var processor = "No Processor Installed";
> var tested_by = "FM";
> var psu = "None";
> var data_storage = "Not Installed";
> var grade = "B";
> var serial_no = "24234234";
> var hp_models = "D2200-VC"
> ```

Notice above var hp_models = "value" is one the variables that has dynamic variable name and I want to convert this variable to static name. The reason is that if I am viewing Dell, IBM, or other models this variable name will be changing dynamically to vendor name, for example "var ibm_models",  "var dell_models", "var sony_models" and so on. I want to convert this variable name to a static name such somemodel or prodmodel regardless of the vendor.

So I should be able to use it something like following.

```
<?php
echo $_models;
?>
```

I should be able to get the value of the variable regardless of the vendor name. So with this variable I am using "_"  underscore as a separator, only the first part changes dynamically for each record and the second part which is models is static.

I hope I was able to explain well.

Comment: This code is highly dangerous. You're directly dumping PHP data into a javascript context. You **MUST** json_encode() the data to prevent any JS metachars in the text from causing syntax errors and killing your JS code block. As for your structure. `var models['hp'] = 'D2200-VC'` will probably serve you better.

Comment: so how do I convert this dynamic variable to a static variable?

Comment: Your changing name always ends with "_models"?

Comment: Thats correct, changing name always ends with _models and it never changes, only the first part before underscore is dynamic in nature.

Comment: I thought it was not difficult to achieve what I want above, but so far I have not received any suggestions, come on gentlemen give me some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the desired results by using preg_replace.

```
    <?php
    if ($this->arrCustomFields) {
        foreach ($this->arrCustomFields as $field) {

            if($field['blnView']) {
$field['lbl']->Name = preg_replace("/.*Models/", "mymodels", $field['lbl']->Name);
                echo 'var '.preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($field['lbl']->Name)).' = "'.$field['lbl']->Text.'";';
            }

        }

    }
?>
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2284641/johannes-h